# What is the difference between BigInt and "Computer Algebra System" integers?

Tags: architecture, math

Obviously I imagine a CAS does more than BigInt does. But I'm wondering if there is a difference in implementation between [BigInt integers](https://silentmatt.com/blog/2011/10/how-bigintegers-work/) and CAS integers (whatever they may be, [symbols](https://github.com/aantthony/javascript-cas/tree/master/lib)?).

Wondering because I would like to implement a robust math system eventually and am not sure yet if BigInt would be pointless if you had a CAS.

What is the major difference between implementations of BigInt vs. CAS integer?

Comment: A BigInt package will be a part of almost any CAS. Certainly Mathematica, Maple, and Matlab have BigInt support. There are [*many* different implementations of arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software), so you'd have to specify which CAS and which BigInt library you'd like to compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, a BigInt type is a CAS that knows only integers. Any CAS will include something very similar to a BigInt. But in addition to that, it needs to understand all the other objects and operations, and how they interact.

The point of a CAS is that it implements the actual mathematical definitions instead of relying on hardware-supported types that are very fast but have implicit rounding or overflows.

Comment: *The point of a CAS is that it implements the actual mathematical definitions instead of relying on hardware-supported types that are very fast but have implicit rounding or overflows.* - which fits also to BigInts, so this is no criteria to distinguish them. Maybe you did not meant it as a criteria, but currently it is easy to misread your answer that way.

Comment: @DocBrown: that is not a misreading at all. See the first sentence of the answer.